# Tailoring file on kickstarted RHEL7.4 installation causes OSCAP plugin to not remediate

Tags: rhel7, kickstart, openscap

I'm having trouble getting RHEL7.4 to use a tailoring file with the OSCAP addon . I've taken the following steps to make this work.

- Created a customization RPM using the scap-workbench tool
- Added that RPM to the kickstart installation
- Specified that I want OSCAP to use the tailoring file as so:

  ```
  content-type = scap-security-guide
  profile =  xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_stig-rhel7-disa_custom
  tailoring-path = ../../usr/share/xml/scap/ssh-rhel7-ds/tailoring-xccdf.xml
  ```

I have tried to copy the tailoring file to /root/openscap_data, but I can't find a hook inside kickstart that would allow me to copy the file there before the OSCAP addon executes.

However, the OSCAP plugin doesn't seem to execute when the tailoring-path is specified, and no error or warning is emitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there were recent fixes to OSCAP addon related to tailoring in kickstart file:

- https://github.com/OpenSCAP/oscap-anaconda-addon/issues/36
- https://github.com/OpenSCAP/oscap-anaconda-addon/issues/41

Both issues were fixed in version 0.8.

But there is still one standing:

- https://github.com/OpenSCAP/oscap-anaconda-addon/issues/40

Which means that the tailoring file should reside in `/tmp/openscap_data`.

I'm afraid there is no easy workaround. 
Something that may work is providing an `update.img` during installation, to use OSCAP addon 0.8, and use an RPM package that provides tailoring content in `/tmp/openscap_data`.

Hope this helps.